# Using Response.Write and Response.Redirect at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Below is Asp.net mvc code,

```
        public void Index()
        {
            Response.Write("Hey");
            Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
        }

 OR

 public void Index()
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
            Response.Write("Hey");
        }
```

Here, Redirecting is working but not the Write(). Why Redirect is being given a preference? I mean why 302 and why not 200 in http response.

Note: This is not for addressing any real time scenario. Just have curiosity to know the reason or underlying behavior.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen/see? `Redirect` says to the browser "forget about this page - what you want is over there ->"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respose.Write is working but when you execute Redirect the server sends a response with the headers:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
>
> Location: somewhere/newlocation.aspx

The browser then initiates another request (assuming it supports redirects) to somewhere/newlocation.aspx loading its contents in the browser.

Anyway, if the response stream is buffered ("Hey") you are overwriting this response with Response.Redirect.

Comment: I mean why 302 and why not 200 in http response

Comment: Because Response.Write is buffered and will only actually start outputting when the server-side code has finished running. And in this case, it only finishes running after you've told it to Redirect, so you're just transmitting the 302 code.

Comment: @Juann Strauss: Sorry I didnt get you

Comment: You are telling the server to transmit a 200 status when it's done processing, but then you interrupt it and tell it to send a 302 status. It's kind of like telling your wife to pack a suitcase because you're going on a short trip, but then halfway through, you tell her "nah, we'll just go out for dinner instead". The suitcase never gets loaded into the car.

Comment: But reverse is also not working. Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com"); Response.Write("Hey"); I mean this time telling dinner first time and telling short trip at second. But my wife still prefers for the dinner:(

Comment: If you are in google and your wife at home she can't give you nothing. And you go to google (response.redirect) before your wife try to give you a "Hey" ;)

Comment: Did I really go to google. Since I am in middle (I mean one more line to go)

Comment: Yes, you are in google. Doesn't matter if you have hundreds of lines of code before response.redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Here not given preference to Redirect , you are calling both Responce.Write and Responce.Redirect in same function then after write page directly redirect to your given url.

Answer (score 0):

If you HAD some real-world scenario where you needed to do something like this, you could do the Response.Write in your code-behind/Controller (depending on if you're using WebForms or MVC) and add the redirect header in the body of your HTML page:

Controller:

```
public void Index()
{
    Response.Write("Hey");
}
```

HTML:

```
<%
//response would show here
%>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=https://www.google.com" />
</head>
```